# how to add a two different popup using "jQuery Popup Overlay" plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery. So can you pls help me to add two different popup with two different button using this jQuery plugin?

[jQuery Popup Overlay](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?BlLWL8ij)

```
  <!-- Add an optional button to open the popup -->
  <button class="my_popup_open" href="#my_popup">Open popup</button>

  <button class="my_popup_open" href="#sam">Open popup</button>

  <!-- Add content to the popup -->
  <div id="my_popup">

   my_popup

    <!-- Add an optional button to close the popup -->
    <button class="my_popup_close">Close</button>

  </div>

   <div id="sam">

   sam

    <!-- Add an optional button to close the popup -->
    <button class="my_popup_close">Close</button>

  </div>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Initialize the plugin
      $('#my_popup').popup();
      $('#sam').popup();

    });
  </script>
```

by this we can add one one popup..

Comment: i have just added some codes

Comment: What code ? Show us your effort !

Comment: You just copied and pasted from the home page of that popup plugin... nice try. If there was a "Close due to LAZINESS", I'd vote for that! This is awful.

Comment: Right-click and view source. Go to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), recreate what you have and edit your question with the code. Makes it easier for others to help.

Comment: sorry guys.. here is the working of the code i tryed. http://jsfiddle.net/vfoLL639/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    // Initialize the plugin
    $('#my_popup').popup();
    $('#sam').popup();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="my_popup_open">Open My Popup</button> // the class name states which popup to open - 'my_popup'
<button class="sam_open">Open Sam</button> // the class name states which popup to open - 'sam'
<div id="my_popup">my_popup
    <button class="my_popup_close">Close</button> // the class name states which popup to close - 'my_popup'
</div>
<div id="sam">sunu
    <button class="sam_close">Close</button> // the class name states which popup to close - 'sam'
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as i saw demo you have one div with a an id which in script you add popup property to that div
so simply add two div then in script add to both divs that popup property like this :

```
<div id="my_popup1">

    ...popup1 content...  

  </div>
<div id="my_popup2">

    ...popup2 content...  

  </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Initialize the plugin
      $('#my_popup1').popup();
      $('#my_popup2').popup();

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: so how can i open "my_popup1" and "my_popup2" popup with different button?

Comment: for example in a button onclicking function try this : $('#my_popup1').popup('show');

Comment: @Sam Do you know how to make a button? Have you worked with Javascript or jQuery at all?

Comment: @Devlish i have.. u can see what i have done with the code. http://jsfiddle.net/vfoLL639/